# Valgrind says "definitely leak" but is it?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind, free

I am trying to write a Monte Carlo Tree Search for tic-tac-toe game but there are real memory problems (e.g. my computer runs out of memory) while running it.

So I decided to investigate situation with `valgrind`.

Below, one of code block that `valgrind` says 'definitely leak'.

```
void player_init (Player **p, player_t symbol)
{
  *p = (Player *) malloc (sizeof (Player));
  (**p).symbol = symbol;
  (**p).score = 0;
}

void player_init_all (Player ***p)
{
  *p = (Player **) malloc (sizeof (Player *) * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      (*p)[i] = (Player *) malloc (sizeof (Player));
    }
  player_init (&(*p)[0], PLAYER1);
  player_init (&(*p)[1], PLAYER2);
}

void player_destroy (Player *p)
{
  free (p);
}
```

where `Player` and `player_t`

```
typedef char player_t;
typedef struct player Player;
struct player {
    player_t symbol;
    unsigned score;
};
```

And they are used in that way;

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Player **players;
    player_init_all (&players);

    // OTHER FANCY CODE HERE

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      player_destroy (players[i]);

    free (players);
    free (board);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I passing pointers around in wrong way?

Valgrind Dump;

```
==21657== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 15
==21657==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21657==    by 0x40147D: player_init_all (main.c:348)
==21657==    by 0x401698: main (main.c:426)
==21657== 
==21657== 16 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 15
==21657==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21657==    by 0x4014AF: player_init_all (main.c:351)
==21657==    by 0x401698: main (main.c:426)
```

where `Line 348` is start of `player_init_all` and `Line 351` start of the `for` loop in the `player_init_all`

Comment: Aren't you doing two `malloc`s per player?  The one in the lines valgrind is flagging gets replaced, but not freed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rather obvious memory leak is here

```
void player_init_all (Player ***p)
{
  *p = (Player **) malloc (sizeof (Player *) * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      (*p)[i] = (Player *) malloc (sizeof (Player));
    }
  player_init (&(*p)[0], PLAYER1);
  player_init (&(*p)[1], PLAYER2);
}
```

You allocate memory for `Player` objects inside the above loop. But immediately after that `player_init` will allocate it again and overwrite the values of `(*p)[0]` and `(*p)[1]`, definitely leaking what you allocated in the above loop.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you `malloc` enough space for your array of `Players`:

```
*p = (Player **) malloc (sizeof (Player *) * 2);
```

then `malloc` 3 `Player` structs:

```
(*p)[i] = (Player *) malloc (sizeof (Player));
```

Then in your `init` function you `malloc` the `Players` again:

```
*p = (Player *) malloc (sizeof (Player));
```

This overwrites the initial `malloc`, which is leaked and never `freed`